# Sliding menu implementation in project

Tags: android

Im trying to use Actionbar sherlock as a dependency to my project. I added it in properties but i still get an "R cannot be resolved to a variable" problem. I corrected the JAR mismatch error as well.

Answer (score 0):

**`Observation`**::

- Actionbar sherlock already comes with `android-support-v4.jar`
- And i think your project also contains `android-support-v4.jar`
- So R will not be generated because of duplicate libraries

---

**`Solution`**::

### remove `android-support-v4.jar` from the `libs` folder of your project

---

*Hope this resolves the problem*

***let me know if you have any more errors !***